# Mexican illegal immigration and rape

Tags: united-states, immigration, statistics, illegal-immigration, reference-request

I remember Donald Trump stating that 80% of illegal immigrants coming from Mexico and crossing illegally into the U.S. were raped/sexually abused. I have been trying to find some credible scholarly articles regarding the matter in order to obtain a clearer understanding of the issue, or if any issue exists.

EDIT: prefer open access if possible

Comment: Can you please link to that Trump quote? I dont remember him every saying that

Comment: http://www.mediaite.com/online/trump-completely-misread-fusion-article-about-immigration-and-rape - the link to the article is now invalid @DavidGrinberg

Comment: The title should read.... ***The Illegal Mexican Immigrant Rapists***... or better yet, ***The Spooky Illegal Mexican Immigrant Rapists***... Don't forget Donald Trump also loves the "poorly educated", he just loves'em!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have the Trump quote backwards. I believe he said that 80% were *rapists*, not *raped*.

Comment: I don't know, when i watched the video provided, he says basically "crime is coming into this country, 80% of the women coming in are raped" (i'm assuming he means illegal immigrants). I don't know if this is a fair assumption, but if most of the human traffickers are raping them, and they can get into the country, id say thats crime coming into the country enslaving some to prostitution apparently due to his claims and what i found looking into the subject. But I want to find facts to either dismiss or approve of this remark. @Bobson

Comment: @Bobson No, it seems to be [correct](http://edition.cnn.com/2015/07/01/politics/donald-trump-immigrants-raping-comments/): "About 80% of the women coming in", he then gets a bit off-topic, but the implication is that the sentence should have ended in "are raped". His broader point is about criminals coming in though: "Well, somebody’s doing the raping, Don! I mean somebody’s doing it! [...] Who’s doing the raping?"

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not really a question about politics. Fact-checking questions should be posted on skeptics.se. I would migrate it there, but skeptics would only accept it if you can state where exactly Trump said that.

Comment: @EricLawson - Interesting.  I didn't watch the video, so I just assumed based on other things he said.

Comment: To add on to what @Philipp stated about this being non-political, don't be surprised if you have a ton of question about what the US political leader, the POTUS, says and you have a question about that and you post accordingly and you're told it's not political. Unfortunately, with the president we have now and some of the stuff he says and the correlated public questions (like huh...), it has nothing to do with politics even though he's the politician saying the things people question... yet, it's not political when you ask the question about what the politician is talking about, etc.

Comment: not exactly about illegal migrants from mexico but this report from CBC (http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/manitoba/illegal-border-crossers-criminal-records-cbsa-union-1.4069820) has some interesting stats: "Nearly half of recent illegal border crossers have criminal records, CBSA union says..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trump actually names the source for this statistic:

> If you go to Fusion, you will see a story: About 80% of the women coming in, you know who owns Fusion? Univision! Go to Fusion and pick up the stories on rape.

The [Fusion](https://fusion.net/is-rape-the-price-to-pay-for-migrant-women-chasing-the-1793842446) article is available online and explains where the number comes from:

> A staggering 80 percent of Central American girls and women crossing Mexico en route to the United States are raped along the way, according to directors of migrant shelters interviewed by Fusion.

This does not seem like a reliable approach to getting correct numbers. Fusion actually also names an [Amnesty International report](https://fusiondotnet.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/amr410142010eng.pdf) which puts the number at 60%, but also names a study - with a small sample size - that puts the number even lower:

> Women and girl migrants, especially those without legal status travelling in remote areas or on trains, are at heightened risk of sexual violence at the hands of criminal gangs, people traffickers, other migrants or corrupt officials. Sexual violence, or the threat of sexual violence, is often used as a means of terrorizing women and their relatives. Many criminal gangs appear to use sexual violence as part of the “price” demanded of migrants. According to some experts, the prevalence of rape is such that people smugglers may require women to have a contraceptive injection prior to the journey as a precaution against pregnancy resulting from rape.
>
> It is a widely held view – shared by local and international NGOs and health professionals working with migrant women – that as many as six in 10 migrant women and girls are raped. [21] A study in 2006 interviewed 90 migrant women held in Iztapalapa Migrants’ Detention Centre, of whom just over half were from Central America. Twenty-three women reported experiencing some kind of violence, including sexual violence. Of these, 13 stated the person responsible was a state official. [22] Researchers carrying out the study believed the figures may significantly understate the problem because of the reluctance of women to discuss sexual violence, particularly when they are in detention.

At least the first cited report is available [online](http://www.cepal.org/celade/noticias/paginas/2/11302/lmora.pdf), but not in English.

The implication Trump is trying to make - that most/many undocumented immigrants are criminals and/or rapists is not supported by this number though. The answer to the question "Who’s doing the raping?" is not "80% of illegal immigrants", but "criminal gangs, people traffickers, other migrants or corrupt officials".

Comment: Thank you for being a seemingly decent unbiased perspective. I was not sure what he was referencing to when he said fusion, didn't realize that was the journal name and confused me since the clip seemed out of context and the initial link within the article (first hyperlink) gave me an error.

Comment: From the quotes above, trump seems to be saying that those migrants are victims of rapes, not the perpetrators of such rapes. I didn't hear him saying but an extension of his argument could be that as those crimes are committed during their migration, shutting down migration would help combat such crimes.

Comment: @dannyf You didn't hear him saying that because he never said anything like it, because that's not his point. His point is that most undocumented immigrants are criminals. That's why he is saying "Somebody is doing the raping". Trumps campaign wasn't build on trying to combat rape, but on spreading fear of immigrants. The context where this discussion is taking place is this: "They're sending people that have lots of problems, and they're bringing those problems with us. They're bringing drugs. They're bringing crime. They're rapists."

Comment: @dannyf But yes, Trump is indeed saying that those 80% are victims of crimes. But not out of concern for them, but to make a point about the dangers of letting immigrants in. Here is the [interview](http://edition.cnn.com/videos/us/2015/07/01/donald-trump-comments-sot-tsr.cnn). Note that it is a direct reaction to the Trump quote in my previous comment.

Comment: ." But not out of concern for them, " I don't have any capability to read his mind, particularly his mind some times back. So I would rather other experts like you to handle that.

Comment: @dannyf You were the one trying to read his mind, speculating on what he may have meant, without any indication that this may actually be the case. I was providing the context of what he actually said. And that context is not rape prevention, but Trumps statement that Mexico is sending it's people to the US, and that those people are rapists.

Comment: The staggering amount of hoops @dannyf constantly jumps through to twist what Trump says into some sort of defensible 'misunderstanding' is truly impressive.